# New Jersey Dairies

Tags: geospatial, agriculture

Looking for a shapefile/FileGDB (any type of spatial data) of all the New Jersey dairies. I have found a Washington state layer here http://geography.wa.gov/data-products-services/data/data-catalog but I cannot find the same or similar layer type for NJ

Comment: Have you look it up on google on search NJ Geospatial ? https://www.google.com/#q=new+jersey+geospatial+data+clearinghouse

Comment: yep, nothing found so far

Comment: How about contact to their State GIS Office and they may help you out on that one ?

Comment: that is a good idea

Comment: You could try openstreetmap.org, but since most states require businesses to register with a "type of business" code, it would be better to contact the State of New Jersey, or at least visit their website.